# How do I make my userscript execute code in isolated sandbox and unsafeWindow too?

Tags: javascript, function, sandbox, execution, userscripts

For most of my code in my userscript, I'm need to use `unsafeWindow` for the websites my script executes on. I do this by using `// @grant unsafeWindow`. However, some of my code cannot be executed with `unsafeWindow` and needs to run in Tampermonkey's isolated sandbox. How would I be able to do this? Something like this could work:

```
function disableUnsafeWindow() {
    // Disable UnsafeWindow
}

function enableUnsafeWindow() {
    // Enable unsafeWindow
}
function withUnsafeWindow() {
    enableUnsafeWindow()
    // Run the code using unsafeWindow
}

function withoutUnsafeWindow() {
    disableUnsafeWindow();
    // Remove unsafeWindow access and execute the code without unsafeWindow
}

withUnsafeWindow()
withoutUnsafeWindow()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the isolated sandbox with the privileged userscript functions by default. Then, for the code that requires use of the native page, you could insert the code into a `<script>` tag, eg:

```js
const fnToRunOnNativePage = () => {
  console.log('fnToRunOnNativePage');
};

const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
script.textContent = '(' + fnToRunOnNativePage.toString() + ')();';
// to use information inside the function that was retrieved elsewhere in the script,
// pass arguments above
script.remove();
```